# Typescript error TS1005: '(' expected

Tags: angular, typescript

This is crazy. I just wanted to declare the variable for array. A simple declaration generat TS1005. I upgraded Typescript version as well but no luck.

```
errorList = Array<{severity: string}>;
```

Current version of Typescript is 2.8.3.

Comment: define the type of your errorList , then assign a value of that type on right side of your '=' , what you have written on right should be the type of errorList [like how mates are mentioning in answers below.]

Answer (score 6):

```
errorList = Array<{severity: string}>;
```

should be

```
errorList: Array<{severity: string}>;
```

You have to define your array with `:` for initialization you need to use `=` operator.